# Programmatically check a Scala class type contains any `var` variable

Tags: scala

I would like check if a class at runtime programmatically to see it contains any `var` declaration, is it possible to achieve this in Scala? thank you.

My intention is to check the given class is stateless or not. thank you.

Comment: You can use runtime reflection to check if there are any fields which are non-final, but you can also have mutable collections inside, or other classes which might be mutable, or sth which reads/writes to a database or file - all of that stored in `val`, so this `var` thing would only check the simplest case. And it could be handled with linter at compilation.